# Show whether the homomorphism is an isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $\phi$ be the map from $\mathbb{Z}_{36} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{36}$ defined by $\phi(x)=21x\bmod 36$.

I am having trouble showing whether the function is one-to-one and/or onto.

Any hints/tips/answers are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Where does 12 go?

Comment: $0 \mapsto 0$ and $12 \mapsto 0$. so...

Comment: $\phi(0)=\phi(12)$ but $0\neq12$ so the function is not one-to-one...having trouble with onto now

Comment: ok...let $y \in \mathbb{Z}_{36}$. To find $x$ such that $\phi(x)=y$. which implies to find $x$ such that $21x=y(mod 36)$. But the linear congruence $21x=y(mod 36)$ has solutions iff gcd(21,36) divides $y$. can you conclude now?

Comment: An isomorphism is both one-to-one and onto. Since you know this function is not one-to-one, it is not an isomorphism. Also, you can try to show that $2$ is not in the image of $\phi$, so $\phi$ is not onto.

Comment: @ChinnapparajR i know the $gcd(21,36)$ is $3$...so $3|y$. but im not sure what this tells us...

Comment: Domain and codomain are the same size so...

Comment: Fine! What is the preimage of $4$?. Suppose $4$ has the preimage, then there is a solution $x$ to $21x=4 (mod 36)$. But which is not possible

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: im confused and most likely confusing myself...is the gcd supposed to tell me something clear about whether it is onto...

Comment: Ok! Tell me how  to show  $y$ in Co domain has a pre image $x$ in Domain  under $\phi$ ?

Comment: What is the contrapositive of a if and only if statement?

Comment: there would be a solution to $21x\bmod36=y$?

Comment: Yes, of course!

Comment: so to determine onto, we need to find a $y\in \mathbb{Z}_{36}$ in the codomain such that $\forall y$ we can find a $x\in \mathbb{Z}_{36}$ in the domain such that $21x\bmod36=y$. but how can we use $gcd$ to determine that we can find such a thing?

Comment: Can you heard this result? "Suppose $gcd(a,m)=d$. Then the linear congruence $ax=b(mod m)$ has solutions if and only if $d$ divides $b$"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68597/discussion-between-rover2-and-chinnapparaj-r).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the things you should know is:

$\text{lcm}(a,b) = \dfrac{ab}{\gcd(a,b)}$.

In this case, taking $a = 21$ and $b = 36$, we get that $252$ is the smallest number divisible by $21$ and $36$:

$252 = 21\cdot 12$ and $252 = 36 \cdot 7$.

These factorizations tells us that $\phi(12) = 0$, that is: $12 \in \text{ker }\phi$.

Since $12 \neq 0$ in $\Bbb Z_{36}$, this alone tells us that $\phi$ is not injective.

Another fact you should know, is that in $\Bbb Z_n$, we have that the (additive) order of $0 \leq k < n$ is:

$\dfrac{n}{\gcd(k,n)}$.

With $k = 21$, and $n = 36$, we have that the additive order of $21 = \phi(1)$ is $12 < 36$. Thus $\phi(\Bbb Z_{36}) = \phi(\langle 1\rangle) = \langle \phi(1)\rangle = \langle 21\rangle$ has order $12$ (because $\phi$ is a homomorphism).

Since the order of the image has $12$, but the co-domain has order $36$, $\phi$ is not surjective.

Explicitly, by direct calculation, we have $\phi(\Bbb Z_{36}) =$

$\{0,21,6,27,12,33,18,3,24,9,30,15\} = \langle 3\rangle$.

Comment: what do you mean by the additive oder of $21$ is $12$?

Comment: I mean that $12$ is the smallest positive integer $k$, such that $k\cdot 21$ is a multiple of $36$ (so that $21k \equiv 0\text{ mod }36$).

Comment: i have a similar problem to this one where $\phi(x)=31x\bmod36$...the process you provided for this problem for determining onto doesn't seem to be working since 31 and 36 are relatively prime...any tips?

Comment: If $\gcd(31,36) = 1$ then there are integers $r,s$ such that $31r + 36s = 1$. What happens when you take that equation modulo $36$? What do you know about invertible maps on a finite set?

Answer (score 2):

*Hint*: The greatest common divisor of $21$ and $36$ is $3$. Since $3>1$, you can conclude something.

Comment: well since the $gcd$ does not equal 1 they are not relatively prime to each other